# ASP.NET MVC, How to add a specific filter in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I would like to add a filter in my Model, this filter will change the name of my property so I do not have to change the name in each view I display the property. I forgot what filter to use and how to syntax it maybe someone can help me on this one?

**Model Code:**

```
namespace InstMvc4Rzr.Models
{
    public class Steps
    {
        public long ProductId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now if I remember correctly we can add a filter above 'public long ProductId' something like [Filter Name="Product"] now instead of the View code showing the property name as "ProductId" it will now show it as "Product" on the webpage.

I've tried searching everywhere for this filter but I cannot find it. It was once in a youtube video but of course since this video contained useful information google removed it.

Comment: They are called `Attributes`, not filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for DataAnnotations under namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Here's a sample:

```
public partial class Employee {
    public class EmployeeMD {
        [Display(Name = "Last Name", Order = -9, 
        Prompt = "Enter Last Name", Description="Emp Last Name")]
        public object LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Manager", AutoGenerateFilter=false)]
        public object Employee1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396